# How do I create a hashed index of tokens using PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, hash, pymongo

Hi so I am trying to create a hashed index with PyMongo for a variable named terms. Originally (before I was trying to use a hashed index) I had written:

```
mycol.update_one({"token":term}, {"$set": {p: {"doc": doc_id, "freq": freq}}}, True)
```

and this worked exactly how I wanted, it was just taking far far far too long (a couple days to finish). I read that using a hashed index speeds things up a lot, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to create the index correctly. I was thinking I had to do something like

```
mycol.create_index({"token":"hashed"}, {"$set": {p: {"doc": doc_id, "freq": freq}}})
```

but then I'm not sure how I would actually make token contain the term that I want to insert into the database with that information.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the problem please ? You said it takes a couple days to finish. Finish an update one operation ?